# Redirect(to specific page) Background notifications in react js web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, push-notification, background

in web react js we catch the background notification event in 'firebase-messaging-sw' this file but for redirection and some data pass there is no option so please tell me how we can pass data or catch event in the application other than this file

we add redirection in 'firebase-messaging-sw' but packages are not imported there so i want to catch event in root files like index.js

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.